Integral of a measurable function with parameter is measurable?
Say that $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is an open set, is a function such that:

$f(x,\cdot)\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$ for a.a. $x\in\Omega$

$f(\cdot,s)$ is measurable for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$.


Question: How can we prove that for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $F_s:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$,
$$F_s(x)=\int_{0}^s f(x,\tau)\ d\tau,\text{ for a.a. }x\in\Omega,$$
is measurable (with respect to Lebesgue measure)?

If f is jointly measurable then this is part of Fubini's theorem. Separate measurability isn't sufficient in general, but since we're working on Polish spaces, there might be a result that separate implies joint measurability; I don't recall off the top of my head.

I don't see how you can apply Fubini's theorem here. Can you detail a little, please?

See for instance https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_of_Vertical_Section_of_Measurable_Function_gives_Measurable_Function. Although not all books write it explicitly, part of the statement of Fubini's theorem (though not all books write it out explicitly) is that both iterated integrals make sense; in particular, the integrand of the outer integral is a measurable function, and that's what you have here.

So the statement here (again, with the stronger hypothesis of joint measurability) will be proved as part of any proof of Fubini's theorem.

Now I understand! Thank you very much!

What about this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647235/counterexample-to-measurable-in-each-variable-separately-implies-measurable.
